# Django Foreign Key Dropdown Filter

Tags: python, django

I have a model called `Listing` which is basically a job listing posted by my users. One of the fields is a Foreign Key called Address (since a user can have multiple addresses). Here is my models.py:

```
class JobListing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey('CustomerAuth.CustomerProfile')
    address = models.ForeignKey('CustomerAuth.Address')
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
class JobListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = JobListing
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'address', 'customer']
```

and finally the relevant parts of my views.py:

```
def create_listing(request):
    form = JobListingForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        listing = form.save(commit=False)
        listing.save()

        current_user = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        listing.customer = current_user
        listing.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/listings/id/%s' % listing.id)

    context_dict = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'listing/create-listing.html', context_dict)
```

As it currently stands when a user selects an address from the dropdown it shows everyones address. Is there anyway I can filter it so that only the addresses entered by that user is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forms.py

```
class JobListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = JobListing
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'address', 'customer']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JobListingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['address'].queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=user)
```

in your views file

```
def create_listing(request):
    user = request.user
    form = JobListingForm(user, request.POST or None) #pass request.user
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
model1.objects.get(pk=1).model2_set.all()
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to Django, do I add this to my views?

Comment: Yes from where you want to send the result to the html file

Comment: Dont be sorry bro. We do mistakes then learn only. Even i dont know a lot of things. Learning when i too face problems.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that. However I'm still having a bot of trouble incorporating it into my code. I've updated my original post to include my views.py. Do you mind explaining how/where I would add it specifically.